# How do I split messages between different queues evenly?

Tags: java, python, ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to change a RabbitMQ cluster I created. I want to have one node that would hold a stats/disck. And I want to have two more nodes that would work in RAM.

How do I create a queue on each server, and make exchange evenly distribute messages between queues?

For example, I want to spread messages between two queues. If I send 100 messages to the cluster, I want 50 messages in each queue.

How do I do this?

Comment: And that is why I am moving from RabbitMQ to [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/)

Comment: @RickyA I need a broker, some place to hold the messages

Comment: zmq sockets have there own queue. When you get the hang of it you see that these monolithic broker architectures are more of a pain than that they solve your problems.

Comment: Don't use multiple queues, add multiple nodes reading from the same queue. The nodes will balance themselves automatically. We have queues with 50 and 75 nodes, depending on what task they're supposed to do.

Comment: The reason I asked that: Right now I have one Q that is sitting on node A, all messages are persistent, sometimes we have a huge spikes, and all messages are going to the same node. We use load balancer in front. But even if I see connections are evenly distributed between nodes, I still suspect that if I connected to node B, it will internally go to node A and grab message from there.

Comment: What I'm trying to achive is: that all nodes would work during this spike, and if load balancer routes request to node B, I don;t want it to go to node A and grab message from there.

Comment: the Tin Man has the right answer: 2 consumers pulling from the same queue will split it 50/50. Add more consumers to share the load proportionally.

Comment: What abput producers (specially exchanges) how to blanace messages between queues?